# wfuzz default number of connects in parallel per target?

Tags: brute-force, hydra

In Hydra, default number of connects in parallel per target is 16 and it can be changed with `-t` flag.

E.g. `-t 100` for 100 connection in parallel per target.

```
wolf@linux:~$ hydra -h | grep parallel
  -t TASKS  run TASKS number of connects in parallel per target (default: 16)
  -T TASKS  run TASKS connects in parallel overall (for -M, default: 64)
wolf@linux:~$
```

What about wfuzz? I did not see this info in it's help menu. Is it possible to change it's value?

```
wolf@linux:~$ wfuzz -h | egrep -i 'thread|parallel'
wolf@linux:~$
```

Comment: Never worked with wfuzz but after 2 minutes looking at the [documentation](https://wfuzz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/basicusage.html#perfomance) I found: *"You can increase or decrease the number of simultaneous requests to make your attack proceed faster or slower by using the -t switch."*.

Answer (score 1):

In this blog post `https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/wfuzz-and-webslayer/` It shows that the default threads Number Is 20 and you can set the Number of thread Udine `-t` flag